# Automatically hibernate computer laptop 10 minutes after its lid was closed

Tags: windows-10, laptop, hibernate

In the Windows power options menu, it is possible to have it go to sleep when the lid is closed:

[image]

Is it possible to extend this functionality (or install a program) to automatically hibernate after the lid has been closed (or it has been asleep) for a certain amount of time?

Comment: No, it isn't because nothing can run whilst the PC is sleeping.

Comment: Depending on how complete your advanced power management menu is for any one power scheme you use, it's possible to choose after how long your PC will hibernate, regarless of its power state. You'd have to check if "hibernate after..." is present in your power options. If not, you can use this freeware standalone to unhide that option: http://www.mediafire.com/file/wt37sbsejk7iepm/PowerSettingsExplorer.zip (if you're uncomfortable downloading that kind of file from unknown sources, as you should be, right-click on the archive and scan it with your antivirus, prior to and after unzipping)

Answer (score 3):

After you close the lid the laptop will enter sleep mode, you can make it enter hibernate after 10min of sleep.

go to control panel>Power options>change plan settings>change advanced power settings and than choose hibernate after:
[poweroptions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T3tU9.png)

and change it to 10min.

if the hibernate after setting doesn't appear (most likely on windows 11)
go to this link:
https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/108391-add-remove-hibernate-after-power-options-windows.html

and download the Add_Hibernate_after_to_Power_Options.reg
run it and restart your computer and it will work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use battery level monitoring to *Hibernate* the computer after it's been in *Sleep* for a while. Unfortunately, this is not tied to an exact time, just an appreciable drop in battery charge.

[image: Setting Hibernate on low battery]

- In the *Power Options* dialog, click on Change advanced power settings.
- Set *Low battery level* to some safe value, perhaps 60% (though I've selected a lower percentage on my laptop).
- Set *Low battery action* to *Hibernate* for *On battery* and/or *Plugged in*.

This way, you can safely close the laptop, knowing the battery will not drain appreciably before going form *Sleep* to *Hibernate*.

Answer (score -2):

[look here for the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0spq.jpg)

Goto Power options > Change plan settings > Advanced settings > *Drop-down 'Sleep' > 'Hibernate after'

and then type the amount of time you want to specify.

The default time will be 180 minutes.